# how to fix Error Linting URL:An internal error occurred while linting the URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am debugging a website's like button and the trusty linter is returning a troublesome error message:

```
An internal error occurred while linting the URL - What is this error?
```

No other details, just this cryptic error. The linter URL that I am using is: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=shopdobau.com

Does anybody know what causes this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have a very similar error message.